# QVTKWidget SetRenderWindow() with PCLVisualizer Exception

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, point-cloud-library

I'm new in PCL. I want to build a project with PCL and VTK int Qt 5.9.6 MSVC 2017 64bit Environment.

My code is like this:

```
// include file
boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer;
```

...

```
// source code file
viewer.reset(new pcl:visualization::PCLVisualizer("viewer", false));
ui->qvtkWidget->SetRenderWindow(viewer->getRenderWindow());
viewer->setupInteractor(ui->qvtkWidget->GetInteractor(), ui->qvtkWidget- >GetRenderWindow());
```

It can be compiled but when I started debugging it goes wrong with alert:

`The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception.
Stopped in thread 0 by: Exception at 0x7ffcb50b1f28, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at 0x25, flags=0x0 (first chance).`

and stopped at line`ui->qvtkWidget->SetRenderWindow(viewer->getRenderWindow());`

After tracking and debugging, I found the problem is that `viewer->getRenderWindow()->GetInteractor()` get the 0x25 value, I don't know how that could happen because a lot of online examples use code like this. And the same program runs healthy on ubuntu 18.04.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: PCL Visualizer does not have own window until it is provided. I guess that `viewer->getRenderWindow()` returns either invalid or null value.

Comment: @AlexanderV Actually, ```viewer->getRenderWindow()``` is valid, I can use its func like ```viewer->getRenderWindow()->GetPosition()```, but the pointer of ```viewer->getRenderWindow()->GetInteractor()``` always points to a strange address ```0x25```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found out that this is a problem caused by the version of VTK. The original version is 8.1.1, and it can be run normally by switching to 8.0.1. But I don't know why it can still be debugged normally in Linux 8.1.1.